# vdproj / msi environment variables

Tags: windows-installer, environment-variables, vdproj

Can somebody please provide me with a (link to a) list of all the environment variables available to vdproj install projects / msi projects ? Is there a comprehensive list any where ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you be a little more specific on what you mean by "environment variables". If you are referring to WI properties here is a complete list: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905(VS.85).aspx